# Take the delimiter that made Scanner to stop

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I am using Java's Scanner to parse some text. Say I have set as a delimiter a variety of characters [@$]

With next I get the text till that delimiter, but I would like for a way to learn if parsing stopped because it found @ or because it found $.

Is there some way to do that? Or should I break it in two, as in try with the first delimiter, and if you fail try with the second?

Comment: Found it! :) You can use scanner.findWithinHorizon("[\\@]", 2) to see if @ was the delimeter found.

Comment: What method do you use to define a delimeter has been stumbled upon?

Comment: useDelimiter("[\\@\\$]") and after just next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! :) 
You can use

```
scanner.findWithinHorizon("[\\@]", 2)
```

to see if @ was the delimeter found.